# GeoServer WMS mastermap zoom issue on Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, zoom

I have a master map consuming it from the PostGIS database via GeoServer. As per understanding if we create a GeoServer layer from PostGIS db then that layer automatically is treated as WMS. But the issue is that I'm not able to increase the zoom level beyond maxZoom level of 18, which is Leaflet's default value. See my code below, where I used  maxZoom: 19 and maxNativeZoom: 18; but when I go beyond 18 the map disappears and gets a blank screen. Is there any way I can increase the maxZoom options in Leaflet?

```js
var map = L.map('map', { maxZoom: 19, maxNativeZoom: 18, center:[50.72204456,-3.53859945], zoom:17 });

L.tileLayer.wms('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/nps/wms', { format: "image/png", layers: ' nps:TopographicLine', transparent: true}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: is there a `MinScaleDenominator` set in the SLD file?

Comment: No, the SLD is not configuration for the layer on geoserver.

Comment: does it work in the GeoServer preview?

Comment: yeah, the layer preview is working in the geoserver; i guess it takes default SLD file setting